# How does one start a Java server in Linux via console?

Tags: java, linux

So I have a Java program sitting on my DigitalOcean server and I have been using the command,

> java -jar IO_Server.jar

To run it. However the problem is that when I type this command in PuTTy, it requires that I keep PuTTy open. If I close PuTTy, the server then shuts down which is not what I want. I need a way to start the server and leave it running even after PuTTy is closed.

I have been trawling the internet for about 2 hours without any luck. I keep coming across the aforementioned command. I have used the command before but I cannot remember what it is nor where I found it.

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`nohup`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup). Something like

```
nohup java -jar IO_Server.jar &
```

The first line of the linked Wikipedia article says

> **nohup** is a [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) command to ignore the [HUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) (hangup) signal.

Comment: and put a & on the end. "nohup does not automatically put the command it runs in the background; you must do that explicitly, by ending the command line with an & symbol." eg. nohup java -jar IO_Server.jar &

Answer (score 1):

To add to Elliott's solution, another option is to use [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) which allows you to open a "new window" run a command and detach from that window. Then, even when you're logged off, the command is still running, and you can re-connect via ssh and re-attach to that window and continue from where you stopped.

Here's a ["getting started guide"](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acuy) to screen.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a screen to run it